# How to build the project in continuum programatically using continuum-xmlrpc-client?

Tags: continuum

I am trying to build project in continuum, programmatically. I am able to add project to continuum by using `continuum-xmlrpc-client.jar`.

When I tried the same for building the project, I got the below error.

```
Failed to invoke method buildProject in class org.apache.maven.continuum.xmlrpc.server.ContinuumServiceImpl: No such object.
    at com.travelport.soa.automation.utils.continuum.ContinuumClient.buildProject(ContinuumClient.java:442)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are getting that error, it's possible that the wrong data is being passed in, and it's not able to find the project that you're requesting. You can check the logs of the Continuum master to see what it reported back to the client, in addition to the exception that you get on the client end.

Here are some examples:
- https://github.com/apache/continuum/blob/CONTINUUM-782/continuum-xmlrpc/continuum-xmlrpc-client/src/main/java/org/apache/maven/continuum/xmlrpc/client/SampleClient.java#L96
- https://github.com/maestrodev/maestro-continuum-plugin/blob/master/src/main/java/com/maestrodev/maestrocontinuumplugin/ContinuumWorker.java#L369